# Given two 2D numpy arrays A and B, how to efficiently apply a function that takes two 1D arrays to each combination of rows of A and B?

Tags: python, arrays, numpy

To be clear, below is what I am trying to do. And the question is, how can I change the function `oper_AB()` so that instead of the nested for loop, I utilize the vectorization/broadcasting in numpy and get to the `ret_list` much faster?

```
def oper(a_1D, b_1D):
    return np.dot(a_1D, b_1D) / np.dot(b_1D, b_1D)

def oper_AB(A_2D, B_2D):
    ret_list = []
    for a_1D in A_2D:
        for b_1D in B_2D:
            ret_list.append(oper(a_1D, b_1D))
    return ret_list
```

Comment: Side note: what is the meaning of the quantity `oper(a, b)`? The scalar projection of `a` on `b` would be different (`a @ b / np.linalg.norm(b)`). When dividing by `b @ b`, you are dividing by norm square.

Comment: This is the coefficient in the vector projection. https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Vector_projection

Comment: The scalar projection is `dot(a, b) / norm(b)` and has a geometric meaning (cosine of the angle between the vectors). Vector projection of `a` onto `b` is `dot(a,b) / dot(b,b) * b` and has the obvious geometrical interpretation. The coefficient you calculate doesn't make sense by itself (in absence of being multiplied by `b`). If you are going to later multiply by `b`, then fine. Otherwise, I don't understand the meaning of it. Just FYI.

Comment: This actually has a meaning. It is just a normalized version of the projection vector. It is a score telling how similar `a_1D` is to `b_1D` in the `b_1D`'s direction. If it is 1, it means `a_1D`'s projection onto `b_1D` is equal to `b_1D`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

this should work.

```py
result = (np.matmul(A_2D, B_2D.transpose())/np.sum(B_2D*B_2D,axis=1)).flatten()
```

but this second implementation will be faster because of cache utilization.

```py
def oper_AB(A_2D, B_2D):
    b_squared = np.sum(B_2D*B_2D,axis=1).reshape([-1,1])
    b_normalized = B_2D/b_squared
    del b_squared
    returned_val = np.matmul(A_2D,b_normalized.transpose())
    return returned_val.flatten()
```

the `del` is there just if the memory allocated by B_2D is too big, (or it's just me being used to working with multiple GB arrays)

**Edit:** as requested for A_1D - B_1D

```py
def oper2_AB(A_2D, B_2D):
    output = np.zeros([A_2D.shape[0]*B_2D.shape[0],A_2D.shape[1]],dtype=A_2D.dtype)
    for i in range(len(A_2D)):
        output[i*len(B_2D):(i+1)*len(B_2D)] = A_2D[i]-B_2D
    return output
```

Comment: Thanks, this is speedy! How can I do a similar thing when `oper(a_1D,b_1D)` returns `a_1D-b_1D` rather than `np.dot(a_1D,b_1D)/np.dot(b_1D,b_1D)`? We are safe to assume that the size of the vectors `a_1D` and `b_1D` are the same.

Comment: just edited my answer with your extra question, be sure to upvote if the solution works.

Comment: okay thx, i expected there would be no way to do a subtraction without a loop, and looks like so.

Comment: there is a way using repmat, however it will take a ton more memory and perform slower than a looped version, so i am not writing it. (it crashed my pc)

Answer (score 1):

Strictly addressing the question (with the reservation that I suspect the OP wants the norm, not the norm squared, as divisor below):

```py
r = a @ b.T / np.linalg.norm(b, axis=1)**2
```

Example:

```py
np.random.seed(0)
a = np.random.randint(0, 10, size=(2,2))
b = np.random.randint(0, 10, size=(2,2))
```

Then:

```py
>>> a
array([[5, 0],
       [3, 3]])

>>> b
array([[7, 9],
       [3, 5]])

>>> oper_AB(a, b)
[0.2692307692307692,
 0.4411764705882353,
 0.36923076923076925,
 0.7058823529411765]

>>> a @ b.T / np.linalg.norm(b, axis=1)**2
array([[0.26923077, 0.44117647],
       [0.36923077, 0.70588235]])

>>> np.ravel(a @ b.T / np.linalg.norm(b, axis=1)**2)
array([0.26923077, 0.44117647, 0.36923077, 0.70588235])
```

Speed:

```py
n, m = 1000, 100
a = np.random.uniform(size=(n, m))
b = np.random.uniform(size=(n, m))

orig = %timeit -o oper_AB(a, b)
# 2.73 s ± 11 ms per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 1 loop each)

new = %timeit -o np.ravel(a @ b.T / np.linalg.norm(b, axis=1)**2)
# 2.22 ms ± 33.3 µs per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 100 loops each)

orig.average / new.average
# 1228.78 (speedup)
```

Our solution is 1200x faster than the original.

Correctness:

```py
>>> np.allclose(np.ravel(a @ b.T / np.linalg.norm(b, axis=1)**2), oper_AB(a, b))
True
```

Speed on large array, comparison to @Ahmed AEK's solution:

```py
n, m = 2000, 2000
a = np.random.uniform(size=(n, m))
b = np.random.uniform(size=(n, m))

new = %timeit -o np.ravel(a @ b.T / np.linalg.norm(b, axis=1)**2)
# 86.5 ms ± 484 µs per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 10 loops each)
other = %timeit -o AEK(a, b)  # Ahmed AEK's answer
# 102 ms ± 379 µs per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 10 loops each)
```

Our solution is 15% faster :-)

Comment: both implementations actually have the same mean runtime when run for 40 times on my machine, i think the 15% less time is by luck or some hardware acceleration on your cpu, also you should **never ever ever** use a**2 when you mean a*a , because this exponentiation is a lot slower than vector multiplication, it actually has slower than linear scaling.